# How to determine whether a string represents an integer?

Tags: matlab, integer, string-comparison

I need to determine if a string contains just an integer. The built-in function `isinteger` is not working.

To avoid loops I'd like to apply this task on cell arrays of strings. 
For example:

```
Q = { 'qf5' ; '4' ; 'true' ; 'false' ; '4.00' ; '4E0' ; '4e0' ; '657' };
```

desired result:

```
integers = 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

For a single string I figured out an ugly workaround, but I can't imagine that this is the only possible way, and also it requires a loop to use it on cell arrays:

```
myString = '4';
integer = uint64( str2double( myString ) );
newString = int2str( integer );
isStringInteger = strcmp(newString,myString);
```

Which essential function am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html

Comment: for single strings its a valid option, but the only possible property would be `digit` which returns logical vectors for a lot of cases. But still the whole vector is just true for an integer, right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html); and to avoid the loop you use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
~cellfun('isempty', regexp(Q, '^-?\d+$'))
```

This considers an "integer" as a string of digits, possibly with one minus sign at the beginning.

Note that `cellfun` with the builtin function `'isempty'` is very fast.

Comment: it does not work for intergers > 9. My mistake, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Oops. Forgot a `+` in the regexp. Corrected

Comment: for me it looks like the speech bubble of an angry Donald Duck now, but it works! thanks!

Comment: @thewaywewalk Hahaha. That's the usual with regular expressions. Type `help regexp` if you want to find out and have some spare time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the string *is* not an integer, therefore the question as such is not correct. What you want to check is whether the string is a representation of an integer. The `isinteger` function is also not what you want, because it does not check whether the actual *content* of a numeric variable is an integer, but whether the *data type* is an integer type.

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in way to check whether a string represents an integer. One approach to implement such a check would be to see whether all the characters in the string represent digits:

```
isintstr = all(myString >= '0') && all(myString <= '9')
```

This code takes advantage of the fact that the decimal digits are encoded in sequence in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) and Unicode.

To allow for leading and trailing white space, use

```
isintstr = all(strtrim(myString) >= '0') && all(strtrim(myString) <= '9')
```

Comment: same issue like for Luis Mendo's answer, it does not work for intergers > 9. My mistake, I should have mentioned it. You're right with your first remark, I changed the title of the question.

Comment: But it does! Did you try it? It looks at all characters in the string. Luis Mendo's answer is better though because it also accounts for a leading `-`, and does the cell array thing you wanted.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood your code first. It is indeed a good solution for single strings.